# Problem using a Stored Proc to read data from a .CSV file to a database

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

Using SQL server 2008 and C# -

So I am trying to implement the feature for a user to import a .CSV file which then I call a Stored Proc to write the contents of that file to a temp table which then gets merged to the actual table.

My question/problem is that I am trying to determine the layout of the .xls file that the customer will need to have and supply them the template .xls file for them to use.  The data is a matrix of shipping rates based on zones.  Therefore the column and row headers are duplicated:

```
 -  A    B    C
 A  1    2    3

 B  2    1    4

 C  3    4    1
```

But I am not sure how to tackle this through a stored procedure. Therefore the other options I had was setting up the .xls template as:

```
From  To   Rate

 A    A     1
 A    B     2
 A    C     3
 B    A     2
 B    B     1
 .....
```

You get the picture.  Doing it this second way would be fairly straight forward and I have a stored proc that would allow me to traverse the data.

However, I am interested in the problem of the first example and figuring out how you would do that.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle?

Comment: Sorry, edited post with SQL server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this.

A simple way is to simply iterate the rows and columns (2 loops) and pass those values to a proc for storage.

Something like (psuedo code):

```
foreach(DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows) {
  foreach(DataColumn col in row.Columns) {
    String value = row[col].Value
    StoreValue(row.Name, col.Name, value); // <-- this would call your proc.
  }
}
```

If you have SQL 2008, then you could use a table value parameter and pass in the entire table to the stored procedure.  From there you could do your inserts.

Comment: Not sure I like this model; you're calling StoreValue X*Y times, resulting in as many calls to the DB. I'd slurp them into a SqlParameter list that is then given to a single command per row (SP or otherwise) to persist a new row in the table.

Comment: @KeithS: my preferred method is actually to pass everything into a TVP and MERGE it with the table it needs to go to.  However, I was just giving a "simple" option to help the OP know how to traverse the structure in a different way than he was currently doing it.

Comment: Well if you used a OLeDB connection to the .xls file - how can you retrieve the Excel version of the file, in order to swap out the "Extended Properties" value depending on the version of excel used in the connection string: "string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="+FileToConvert+";Extended Properties=Excel <#.#>"

Comment: @pghtech: This is a completely different question from your original.  You might consider asking it separately.  My answer is simply that I wouldn't use OLEDB to open an excel file; instead I'd use a third party library for dealing with it.

Comment: @Chris - Thanks.  However, I brought up the OleDB because it appears your using DataTables in your example.  The way I found to load the xls into Datatable was through OLEDB (in .NET 2.0).

Comment: @pghtech: This is why I don't use OLEDB: http://www.brianpeek.com/blog/archive/2006/04/18/415.aspx  The problem and workaround is more than a little disconcerting and 3rd party libraries do this better.